# Analyze BSOD WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR WIN8 Driver

Tags: windows, crash, crash-reports, crash-dumps, windowserror

I have a new Computer for 3 Weeks now and i get a lot of WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR BSODs.
I get These Bluescreens random every 30 - 50 minutes.

Here is the dump from WinDbg:

---

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\050913-7984-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\Symbole*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 8 Kernel Version 9200 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 9200.16551.amd64fre.win8_gdr.130306-1502
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`04018000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`042e4b00
Debug session time: Thu May  9 17:12:45.597 2013 (UTC + 2:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:00:25.246
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
..................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
.......

---

- *
- Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
- *

  ---

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 124, {0, fffffa8008c87028, be200000, 2110a}

Probably caused by : GenuineIntel

### Followup: MachineOwner

1: kd> !analyze -v

---

- *
- Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
- *

  ---

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: fffffa8008c87028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000be200000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 000000000002110a, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

### Debugging Details:

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  f

STACK_TEXT:
fffff880`009f9868 fffff801`0479193d : 00000000`00000124 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`08c87028 00000000`be200000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`009f9870 fffff801`04178969 : 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`066d7320 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`08c87028 : hal!HalBugCheckSystem+0xf9
fffff880`009f98b0 fffff801`047916e3 : 00000000`00000728 00000000`00000001 fffff880`009f9a10 fffffa80`066d7320 : nt!WheaReportHwError+0x249
fffff880`009f9910 fffff801`0479100c : 00000000`00000010 fffffa80`066d7320 fffff880`009f9ac8 fffffa80`066d7320 : hal!HalpMcaReportError+0x53
fffff880`009f9a70 fffff801`04790f07 : fffffa80`0678b760 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandlerCore+0xd4
fffff880`009f9ac0 fffff801`04790d64 : 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandler+0xe3
fffff880`009f9b00 fffff801`04791edb : fffffa80`0678b760 fffff880`009f9d30 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandlerWithRendezvous+0xd4
fffff880`009f9b30 fffff801`0407057b : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalHandleMcheck+0x40
fffff880`009f9b60 fffff801`0407032e : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxMcheckAbort+0x7b
fffff880`009f9ca0 fffff880`0158e984 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiMcheckAbort+0x16e
fffff880`02e1b888 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : intelppm!MWaitIdle+0x18

STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: GenuineIntel

IMAGE_NAME:  GenuineIntel

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_CACHE

BUCKET_ID:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_CACHE

### Followup: MachineOwner

---

I have also reinstalled Windows 3 times now but every time i get These Errors.
Can anyone tell me whats the Problem is?

Greets

Comment: It looks like it originated in intelppm, which I believe is Process Power Management. See http://www.eightforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/8116-whea_uncorrectable_error.html for some PPM related features you can disable (SpeedStep, C-State).

Answer (score 0):

This might cause by INTEL CPU driver, for energy management or etc. try not to install intel cpu driver(might delivered with motherboard).